# Automatic selection of the destination App in UIDocumentINteractionController without presenting the available Apps

Tags: ios, audio, share, uidocumentinteraction, socialshare

I am developing and App for sharing an audio file with Whatsapp. Since, I am only focused on Whatsapp, I am not interested on showing other available apps such as VLC or Telegram.

Can I select Whatsapp App to share the file without presenting the menu for choosing? In other words, can I avoid presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:anmiated:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use UIDocumentInteractionController UTI: `net.whatsapp.audio`

[Custom URL scheme for whatsApp](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013)

```
  _documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
_documentController.delegate = self;
_documentController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.audio";
[_documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES]
```

> When triggered, WhatsApp will immediately present the user with the contact/group picker screen. The media will be automatically sent to a selected contact/group.

Comment: Thank yo very much. However, I managed to show WhatsApp app in the menu. I was wondering if I can avoid the presentation of the menu, and  skip the WhatsApp icon triggering.

Comment: @CRoig - did you manage to solve your original problem? (skip the triggering?)

Comment: I was trying to share music to WhatsApp as well, but even with `_documentController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.audio";` the Document Controller is showing other apps (dropbox, ifile...) with WhatsApp. Any idea why?

Comment: Nvm, found it. The extension of the file should be `.waa` instead of `.m4a`